# Python : list index out of range error for filling in data set

Tags: python, list, time, append, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a data set `[101,102,105,106,108,111]` with a corresponding times `[1,2,5,6,8,11]`.
I need to fill in the data set with zeros when the difference between the nth and nth + 1 time is not 1. so far i have tried many and this is one:

```
for i in xrange(0,10):
    if time[i+1]-time[i] != 1:
       d.insert(i,data[i])
    else :
       d.insert(i,0)
```

so overall i want a new time set which is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` and a new date set which is `[101,102,0,0,105,106,0,108,0,0,111]`

Comment: is that actually how your code is indented? that wouldn't work. Also, what is the difference between d and data?

Comment: You're getting an error because you're looping from 0 to 9 and there are only 6 elements in the time list and the data set you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach should work:

```
import itertools

data_set = [101,102,105,106,108,111] 
data_times = [1,2,5,6,8,11]

new_time_set = range(data_times[0], data_times[-1]+1)
new_data_set = []

last_time = data_times[0]

for data, time in itertools.izip(data_set, data_times):
    new_data_set.extend([0] * (time-last_time-1) + [data])
    last_time = time    

print "Data:", new_data_set
print "Times:", new_time_set
```

This prints the following output:

```
Data: [101, 102, 0, 0, 105, 106, 0, 108, 0, 0, 111]
Times: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

**Update** - The script now uses breaks in time, not data to fill in the gaps.

If the time series uses floats:

```
new_time_set = range(int(data_times[0]), int(data_times[-1])+1)
```

Comment: it turns out this isnt what i needed. I made the mistake of using an example where the data is linear.

Comment: Not a problem, just create a new question with some updated data and the new results that you need. Add the code you have so far.

Comment: it turns out this isnt what i needed. I made the mistake of using an example where the data is linear. My actual data is more like '[101,101,102.3,101.2,119.2,103.4]', which corresponds to a time set of '[1,2,5,6,10,13]'. So i need the time to run from 1-13s and a data set that has zeros where no data was acquired at that time. for example i want an output of ' [101,101,0,0,102.3,101.2,0,0,0,119.2,0,0,103.4]' corresponding to '[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]'.
My apologies for the poor question, im new to python

Comment: so far i have:
`time=[1,2,5,6,10,13]
data=[101,101,102.3,101.2,119.2,103.4]

d = []
#t = range(time[0], time[-1]+1)

##
for i in xrange(time[0], time[-1]+1):
    diff = time[(i+1)] -time[i]
    #print diff
    if diff == 1:
        d.append(data[i])
        t.append(time[i])
        d.append(data[i+1])
        i=i+1
        
        if d[i]==d[i-1]:
            d.remove(d[i-1])
        
    while diff > 1:
     
        d.append(0)
        diff=diff-1`

Comment: Try now, it now uses gaps in the times to generate missing data.

Comment: That almost works my only problem is my input times are floats. i.e they are all 1.0,2.0,3.0...etc.. i tried using `int(new_times_set)` but this didnt work

Comment: It is safer to work with ints in this case. See the code update for how to convert.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question which bin the zero goes in, but this should give you an idea of how to tackle the problem:

```
>>> data = [101,102,105,106,108,111]
>>> [0 if (d - data[i-1] == 1) else d for i,d in enumerate(data)]
[101, 0, 105, 0, 108, 111]
>>>
```